# Error en CSV file, Python

Tags: python, csv, data

quiero leer un archivo en mi PC pero me da error, quizás puedan ayudarme

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import logging
csvFile = 'C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/house/GFG.csv'

def __init__(self, _data=csvFile, _shortTerm=10, _longTerm=15):
        self.closingPrices = []

        with open(csvFile,'r') as CSVFile:
            reader = csv.reader(CSVFile, delimiter=';')
            for row in reader:
                self.closingPrices.append(row[4] # Tomo los datos de cierre
        self.closingPrices.pop(0)    # Eliminio primer fila de información 
        self.closingPrices = map(float, self.closingPrices)
        self.data =[]
        self.shortTerm = _shortTerm
        self.longTerm = _longTerm
        self.shortAverage = self.setShortAverage()
        self.longAverage = self.setLongAverage()
        self.lastIndicator = None
        self.init_logging()
```

El error es el siguiente :

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '116,85'

Comment: Seguramente `self.closingPrices` tiene una coma como separador decimal, prueba con `float(self.closingPrices.replace(',', '.'))`

Comment: Nada, no me da resultado

Comment: Si, no presté atención que estas usando un `map` para la conversión, prueba con `map(lambda x: float(x.replace(",",".")), self.closingPrices)`

Comment: Ahora me arroja: 
self.closingPrices.pop(0)   
IndexError: pop from empty list

Comment: Ese es otro error, lo tienes seguramente en `self.closingPrices.pop(0)`, y lo que te dice es que `self.closingPrices` está vacia.

Comment: ue me recomiendas hacer? @PatricioMoracho

Comment: Por empezar revisa esta línea `self.closingPrices.append(row[4] # Tomo los datos de cierre` esta sintacticamente mal ya que falta cerrar paréntesis del `append()`. Revisa también el archivo que no este vacío.

Answer (score 0):

¿Y por que no lo lees con pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer='C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/house/GFG.csv',
    sep=';',
)
```

De esta forma puedes trabajas mucho mejor tu csv, por ejemplo en la parte que haces el `self.closingPrices.pop(0)`, con un dataframe sería.

```
df.drop(labels=0, axis=1) # axis=1 indica columnas
```

La documentación la encuentras en:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

en este [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) también

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias eres muy amable